# Is it possible to decrypt .atp file content into text file using command line or any other tool?

Tags: cmd

I want to decrypt the file content into another text file, I have a file with it's extension is .atp. Is it possible to decrypt this file?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean [_this_ ATP File Extension](https://www.file-extension.org/extensions/atp)?

Comment: @JosefZ, Not that one. Any file, i want to decrypt the file content. How to do?